# Statistical sample with age ranges. How to extrapolate it using the real age distribution over population.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a data set consisting in the classification of the numbers of suicides by age range.
I want to figure out if there is or not association between the number of suicides and the age range. But, obviously, if there are more people (in the real population) in the range of (50,60) than in the range (20,30) I will have more suicides in the range (50,60).

Therefore, I know I have to consider the population distribution. And I have this data. However, I don't know what is the statistical method to do this. I can divide each cell by the weight this range has in the population, and I will obtain "the equivalent sample" with a correct population distribution. However, I want to do inference with this table, for example a Chi Square Test of Independence, and after this artificial change I don't know how to apply this.
Can anyone help? I only need some bibliographic source or some idea. I looked for it, but I found nothing.
Thanks in advance.